# Proxy Rotator PHP

Tags: php, proxy

iam trying to make my script use diffrent ip on evry try using proxy.. like specifying 
4-5 proxies and keeps rotating them randomly, i used this code but somehow not working ?
thnx in advance

```
$proxies = array(
    '101.78.209.133:1080',
    '108.16.231.7:24476',
    '108.30.227.209:50684',
    '109.167.201.26:1080',

);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION,'CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip,deflate");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$agents[array_rand($agents)]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$proxies[array_rand($proxies)]);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're setting the proxy IP address/port to the USERAGENT string in addition to the $agents random element to USERAGENT?

Comment: Sorry, but "somehow not working" is not a helpful description. What does that mean?

Comment: OMG !!! dum mistake :3 it should be CURLOPT_INTERFACE i guess :3

Comment: @ arkasha well i mean it is not changing the ip.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting the `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` instead of `CURLOPT_PROXY`.

Comment: yeah i saw my dum mistake :3 but it should be CURLOPT_PROXY or CURLOPT_INTERFACE ??